# How to quickly get objects from an array based on two properties in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a big array of DataRow objects.  Each object inside the array has 3 properties; FirstName,LastName and Department.  Some of the objects have the same FirstName and LastName but different Departments.  If there is a duplicate, the FirstName and LastName could be anything but one of the object's Department will always be 'Temp Employee' while the other may be anything.

I need to remove all duplicate objects based on FirstName/LastName but if there is a duplicate found to keep the duplicate object that is NOT the 'Temp Employee' department.

I have a function created but it takes a very long time.  There's got to be a better way to do this.

```
function removeDupsFromSamData($aSamData) {
    $aNoDups = @();
    $aTemps = $aSamData | Where-Object { $_.Department -eq 'Temp Employee' } | % { "$($_.FirstName)|$($_.LastName)" }
    $aFtes = $aSamData | Where-Object { $_.Department -ne 'Temp Employee' } | % { "$($_.FirstName)|$($_.LastName)" }

    $aTempsAsFtes = Compare-Object $aTemps $aFtes | % { $_.InputObject }
    $aUniqueEmps = @();
    foreach ($i in $aTempsAsFtes) {
        $sTempFname = $i.Split('|')[0]
        $sTempLname = $i.Split('|')[1]
        $aUniqueEmps += $aSamData | ? { ($_.LastName -eq $sTempLname) -and ($_.FirstName -eq $sTempFname) }
    }##endforeach

    return $aUniqueEmps
}##endfunction
```

Comment: So to clarify: There are SOME temp employees that you want to KEEP ? (Does who doesn't have non-temp object too)

Comment: Correct.  I want to keep all temp employees unless the employee became a FTE (Full time employee) at some time.  In that instance, I want to keep the person's FTE status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be faster. Don't have a big samplefile to measure with unfortunately.

```
function removeDupsFromSamData($aSamData) {

    $aFtes = $aSamData | Where-Object { $_.Department -ne 'Temp Employee' }
    $aTemps = $aSamData | Where-Object { $_.Department -eq 'Temp Employee' }

    $new = @()
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $aFtes -DifferenceObject $aTemps  -Property FirstName, LastName -PassThru | Where-Object { 
        #Unique temp-employee
        $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"
    } | % {
        #Add to "new" list
        $new += $_
    }

    #Add the unique temps
    $aFtes += $new
    $aFtes
}
```

Please measure them with the following if you can. Would be fun to see if it makes any difference:

```
#Your function
Measure-Command -Expression { removeDupsFromSamData $myarr }

#Rename my solution to "newremove" or something
Measure-Command -Expression { newremove $myarr }
```

Comment: The same comment goes to this one from the comment above.  I need to output an array with a set of original objects that was input into the function.  For example, an object in $aSamData has properties like Firstname,LastName,Department and EmployeeID.

Comment: To be honest, that's your fault. The questions specifically says that the array HAS 3 PROPERTIES. Still, this DOES output the original objects, with one additional property `SideIndicator` on the ones that only were temps, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: You are correct.  My fault.  This function IS significantly faster.  Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any faster?

```
function removeDupsFromSamData($aSamData) {


$aTemps = $aSamData | Where-Object { $_.Department -eq 'Temp Employee' } 
$aFtes = $aSamData | Where-Object { $_.Department -ne 'Temp Employee' } 

$ht = @{}

 foreach ($aFte in $aFtes)
  {
   $ht[$aFte.firstname/$aFte.lastname] = $true
  }

 foreach ($aTemp in $aTemps)
  {
  if ($ht[$aTemp.firstname/$aTemp.lastname])
    {continue}

  else {$aFtes += $aTemp}
  }

  $aFtes
}
```

Comment: I had to modify this a little bit but for the most part it worked as it should BUT it only returns the FirstName/LastName string.  It needs to output the original actual object since it has multiple other properties that need to come with it.

Comment: I don't quite understand the comment.  The FirstName/LastName strings are being used in the hash table to de-dupe, but the hash table isn't what's being returned.